# Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to store tab in local storage and fetch that tab in front on refresh page, data got store in local but at the time of feting at console i get error as

> Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe
>   context.

Here is my angularjs code

```
$scope.data=$localStorage.$default({
    tab: [{   
        name:'Default 1',
        page: $sce.trustAsHtml('<tab class="portlet" id="internalTabs">first internal</tab>'),
        image: $sce.trustAsHtml('<img style="float : right; " src = "'+token_url+'images/grp1_setting_icon.png" >'), Width: 100
    }]
});
```

and here is my index code

```
<tabset>
              <tab class="grp_left"
                   ng-model='newTab'
                   sortable-tab
                   ng-repeat="tab in data.tab" 
                   index='{{$index}}' 
                   style='width: {{tab.Width}}%;'
                   id='{{$index}}'
                >
                <tab-heading>
                      {{tab.name}}   <span popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" popover-placement="bottom" rel="popover"><i ng-bind-html="tab.image"></i></span>

                </tab-heading>
                <!-- below is template of popover for add delete and rename tabs-->
                <script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Enter Title : </label> <span ng-click='closePopup($event)' id='closePopup' ><i class="fa fa-times" style='float:right;'>close</i></span>
                     <input type="text" maxlength="12" focus-me='true' ng-model="tab.name" class="form-control ">
                    <button class='btn-warning btn-xl'ng-click='RenameTab($event,tab.name)' style='margin-top:6px;' ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" ></span>Add</button>
                    <button class='btn-danger btn-xl' ng-click='removeTab($event,$index)' style='margin-top:6px;' ><span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ></span>Delete</button>
                   </div>
                </script><!-- end of template code   -->
                <span ng-bind-html="tab.page" ></span>
              </tab>
            </tabset>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: How to resolve "Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996899/angularjs-how-to-resolve-attempting-to-use-an-unsafe-value-in-a-safe-context)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try including angular-sanitize.min.js 
and inject "ngSanitize" in module declaration in addition to this clear localStorage by calling this "$localStorage.$reset();"

Comment: i have included  angular-sanitize.min.js  as well but still facing same issue

Comment: try $localStorage.$reset(); at the start

Comment: I have used that but at remove tabs. thanks it works for me as i put " $localStorage.$reset(); " at start